# How to make scaled Grid items overflow fully on top of every other Grid item in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

### Description:

I have a `GridView` in Flutter where the grid items are scaled using `Transform.scale` and animated with `AnimationController`. However, the problem is that the scaled grid items only overflow on the items that are vertically on top of them, and not with the bottom ones. I want to achieve a layout where the scaled grid items fully overflow on top of every other grid item, regardless of their position. How can I modify the code to achieve this behavior?

Now I totally understand that it is by design as such, and it makes sense when having scaled multiple grid items at once, also not sure if this is a valid way to question, but still need a way for the single item to be on top.

### Screenshot

[image: Check out the red scaled container]

### Expected:

The scaled grid item should be on top of all other grid items.

### Reproducible Code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Reproducible Sample')),
        body: MyGridView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyGridView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        mainAxisSpacing: 4,
        crossAxisSpacing: 4,
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: List.generate(
          randomGridItemsHeight.length,
          (index) {
            return AnimatedFeedItem(
              height: randomGridItemsHeight[index],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<double> randomGridItemsHeight = [
  200,
  180,
  220,
  210,
  190,
  230,
];

class AnimatedFeedItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimatedFeedItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.height,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double height;

  @override
  State<AnimatedFeedItem> createState() => _AnimatedFeedItemState();
}

class _AnimatedFeedItemState extends State<AnimatedFeedItem>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller = AnimationController(
    lowerBound: 1,
    upperBound: 2,
    vsync: this,
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
  );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void playAnimation() {
    _controller.forward().then((value) => _controller.reverse());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Transform.scale(
          scale: _controller.value,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: child,
        );
      },
      child: FeedGridItem(
        color: randomColor(),
        height: widget.height,
        onPressed: playAnimation,
      ),
    );
  }

  Color randomColor() {
    Random random = Random();
    return Color.fromARGB(
      255,
      random.nextInt(256),
      random.nextInt(256),
      random.nextInt(256),
    );
  }
}

class FeedGridItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const FeedGridItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.color,
    required this.height,
    required this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Color color;
  final double height;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  @override
  State<FeedGridItem> createState() => _FeedGridItemState();
}

class _FeedGridItemState extends State<FeedGridItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: widget.onPressed,
        child: Container(
          color: widget.color,
          height: widget.height,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean that tapped square should be on top of the other item?